# does GetComInterfaceForObject pin the object?

Tags: c#, interop

Will using GetComInterfaceForObject and passing the returned IntPtr to unmanaged code keep the managed object from being moved in memory? Or does the clr somehow maintain that ptr? Note that the unmanaged code will use this for the lifetime of the program, and I need to make sure the managed object is not being moved by the GC.(At least I think that's right?)

- EDIT - Alright I found some info and I am thinking that this may be the answer. It deals with delegates, but I would have to believe calling GetComInterfaceForObject does something along the same lines.

[Source of the Following text](http://www.ureader.com/message/1230379.aspx)

"Managed Delegates can be marshaled to unmanaged code, 
where they are exposed as unmanaged function pointers.  Calls on those 
pointers will perform an unmanaged to managed transition; a change in 
calling convention; entry into the correct AppDomain; and any necessary 
argument marshaling.  Clearly the unmanaged function pointer must refer to a 
fixed address.  It would be a disaster if the GC were relocating that!  This 
leads many applications to create a pinning handle for the delegate.  This 
is completely unnecessary.  The unmanaged function pointer actually refers 
to a native code stub that we dynamically generate to perform the transition 
& marshaling.  This stub exists in fixed memory outside of the GC heap.

However, the application is responsible for somehow extending the lifetime 
of the delegate until no more calls will occur from unmanaged code.  The 
lifetime of the native code stub is directly related to the lifetime of the 
delegate.  Once the delegate is collected, subsequent calls via the 
unmanaged function pointer will crash or otherwise corrupt the process.  In 
our recent release, we added a Customer Debug Probe which allows you to 
cleanly detect this  all too common  bug in your code.  If you havent 
started using Customer Debug Probes during development, please take a look!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your edit states (about delegates), your managed object doesn't need to be pinned, since GetComInterfaceForObject returns a "pinned" pointer that calls through to the correct managed object.  However, you will need to make sure that the managed object lives for as long as the COM clients are using the unmanaged pointer to it.

Comment: Awesome! That's what I figured after reading that. Thanks for the response, trying to track down AccessViolationExceptions.